# Vuejs reloads data when I return to page with browser back button

Tags: javascript, frontend, single-page-application, vuejs2

I am using Vuejs 2, and I have list of products, I am fetching data on method created(). When I scroll down and click to product, product information page opened. If I press back button, that list page opened and method created() executes and fetches data again, and I am at the top of the page and I have to scroll down to that product again. Is there a way to return to that position of list where I clicked?

Comment: I handled back button and after fetching data manually scrolled to that product, but I think that is not a good solution

Comment: Well you may prevent the data reloading through caching option of the ajax library you use. For the scrolling, assuming you are using vue-router, have you checked the scrolling behavior in the documentation https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/scroll-behavior.html . You may provide your own functionality.